# Microsoft HTML5Labs WebSockets - How To Use Cookies?

Tags: c#, websocket

Ive been tinkering with Microsoft's [prototype](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/download) WebSocket implementations, specifically the desktop client component (System.ServiceModel.WebSockets).  As far as I can tell, there is no way to attach cookies when opening a client websocket.

Does anyone know if this is possible with their library?

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets isn't HTTP as you know it. It's supposed to be just a little more than a TCP socket. So there aren't any HTTP headers, and so no cookies for each packet.

However, the WebSocket API does use HTTP requests to *establish* the connection. You could send cookies along with the initialization. You could hold onto the cookie and associate it with the open connection.

[Here](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/wiki/Documentation) is documentation to a node.js implementation of WebSockets. They allow you to attach to a `request` event. From the event argument (`WebSocketRequest`) has a `httpRequest` property which will contain your cookies. Of course, this is a moot point if you're not using node.js, but it is a good example of what's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The WebSocket API (http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#parsing-websocket-urls) makes me believe that using cookies should be possible.  In any case, I can work-around by using querystring in url.

Comment: @user163757 Thanks for the link, I updated my answer with another idea